# Offline Caching of Maven Archetypes

Tags: maven, caching, maven-archetype

I'd like to be able to start a project from a Maven archetype while being offline. But I can't find clear instructions on how to cache Maven archetypes for offline use. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Maven archetype is an artifact after all and as such it will be cached automatically by Maven at its first usage. Later usages will always run fetched artifacts first (from local cache). We could also force Maven to only use the cache (offline mode, as explained below).

So you could simply invoke the concerned archetypes once (i.e. for a dummy project) and have them offline for further invocations.

If you really want to cache it upfront, you could use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its [get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) goal to add to your local Maven cache the archetype artifact.

For instance, let's cache the [Maven Quickstart Archetype](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) as following:

```
mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
   -DartifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Dversion=1.0
```

It will hence store on your local Maven cache the `maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar` artifact.

If you don't know where your local Maven cache is, you can use the [Maven Help Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) and run:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository
```

As part of the verbose output, you will get the full path to your local Maven cache.

Since now the QuickStart Archetype is on our cache, we can run it using the `-o` flag (go offline, forced) for the Maven invocation

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \ 
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 \
  -DgroupId=com.sample -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -B -o
```

As such, Maven will run an off-line execution and only use its local cache.

---

Note that you could also use the [`archetypeCatalog`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeCatalog) option while invoking `archetype:generate` and set it to `local` to only check the local catalog, but a forced execution to offline mode (`-o`) would better suit your need (forcing local catalog AND local cached archetypes).

Answer (score 1):

Maven's archetype mechanism relies on catalogs. Catalogs are XML files that maven inspects to see what archetypes are available.
As *[Maven: The complete reference](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html)* states in [Chapter 12.4](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/archetype-sect-publishing.html):

> An Archetype catalog is an XML file which the Maven Archetype plugin can consult to locate archetypes in a repository.

You can create a catalog of your cached archetypes (already downloaded) by crawling your local repository for available archetypes. This is by invoking the [crawl mojo](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/crawl-mojo.html):

`mvn archetype:crawl`

This will create an XML file in `~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml`.
(You can *specify a path* by appending `-Dcatalog=<filename>`)

Once created, you can use the command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://<fullpath of catalog file>
```

e.g.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file:///home/username/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml
```

to generate a project using the newly created catalog. It will *only* show the available (cached) archetypes to you and these can be used offline.

Addendum:

I guess you will use the *mvn archetype:generate* more often, so you might want to minimize typing by using this:

1) Generate the XML archetype catalog under `.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` -

```
mvn archetype:crawl -Dcatalog=/home/<username>/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

2) Use mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local (this accesses `.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

It is a good idea to use this once online, so that all necessary plugins are downloaded. E.g., the [Archetype Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) and potentially others.

Comment: But the catalog will only provide what is already cached, while the question was more about how to cache the archetype beforehands. Moreover, you actually don't need to recreate the local catalog if archetypes are already cached. Anyway, good point to mention it.